SAFARI Browser locally: "Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost."
everyone.
I need help with understanding and solving issue with Safari browser.
There is a running website locally and en issue in console with loading google font, ajax.googleapis and bootstap.min . Website has also links in scripts to other sources (like kit.fontawesome.com or code.jquery) and they works. Here is message from console:

[Error] Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost. (jquery.min.js, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost. (css2, line 0)
[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
Global Code (card-sliding.js:1)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (bootstrap.min.js.map, line 0)

I found this question, but I am not really understand it and my case running not from server.
Would be glad any suggestions and help.
